# How to wait until stream write is done

Tags: c#, networking, networkstream

I have a server app that listens for connections on port 8888. I am also creating the client application. It is a simple application the only hard thing about it is managing multiple connections.   so I just need to send files between computers so the way I do that, I don't know if it is wright but it works maybe you guys can correct me. here is my algorithm when sending the file:

```
NetworkStream stream = \\ initialize it

while(someCondition)
{
  // first I open the file for reading and read chunks of it
  byte[] chunk = fileRead(file, indexStart, indexEnd) // I have a similar method this is just to illustate my point

  stream.Write(chunk, \\other params)

   // since I often send large files it will be nice if I can wait here 
   // until the stream.Write is done. when debuging this the while loop 
   // executes several times then it waits. 

}
```

and on the other side I read bytes from that stream and write it to a file.

I also need to wait sometimes because I send multiple files and I want to make sure that the first file has been sent before moving to the next. I know I can solve this by using the stream.Read method once the transfer has been done. and sending data back from the client. but sometimes I believe it will be helpful to know when the stream.write is done.

---

Edit

ok so based on your answers I can for example send to the client the number of bytes that I am planing to send. and once the client recives that many bytes it means it is done. But my question is if this is efficient. I mean doing something like

on the server:

writing data  "sending the file length"

read data "check to see if the client received the length"  (expecting a string ok for example)

write data "tel the client the name of the file"

read data "check to see if the client recived the name of the file"

write data "start sending chuncks of the file"

read data "wait until client replies with the string ok for example"

Comment: Am I missing something? The stream.Write call is going to be blocking, so it always waits until it is complete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.write.aspx

Comment: I don't think that is the case because before the way I used to tell the client that the file had been sent was by calling the method. stream.Write( "<done>".toByteArray,...)   and that string I sent it obviously when I was done sending the file right. but sometimes that string was received before and chunks of the file later...

Comment: in other words the client the app that was receiving the file I used to check every time if a string of length x was sent and if was equal to "<done>" then to close the file but sometimes the "<done>" was sent before other parts of the file causing the file to be incomplete..

Comment: That sounds like incorrect receiving logic then...

Comment: I just have a loop and inside that I have the stream.read(data...) the data when writen to the file is writen in order but the "<done>" string gets sent with other parts of the file sometimes when sending large files. Otherwise the client will always listen for the "<done>" string.

Comment: You don't need all the 'read data "check to see if the client received the XXX' steps. TCP is a streaming protocol. The peer will receive whatever you send in the order you send it. Just send the length followed by the data, then maybe more {length, data} pairs, then close the socket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The write is complete when the line

```
stream.Write(chunk, \\other params)
```

completes. It's worth noting that this does not imply that the other end has received anything. In fact, immediately subsequent to that line, the data is likely to be in some buffer on the sending machine. That means that it's now out of your control. If you want receipt confirmation, the remote end will have to let you know.

Comment: so that explains everything. that is the reason why the client may receive the "<done>" string combined with chunks of the file right?

Comment: spender take a look at my edit. that means that I will have to do something like my edit. That is the right way to go? I belive it will be more efficient to just send data plus much faster. but as you mentioned there is no way of being sure if the chunk was received by the client...

Answer (score 3):

Stream.Write is synchronous, so it will always block your thread until the writing finishes.